# How to generate URL in ASP.NET / C# for a Single Sign-On (SSO) using PHP form?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, single-sign-on

I have the following PHP form:

```
<?php
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$key = "YOUR_KEY_HERE";
$hkey = hash("sha256", $key, true);
$date = date('D M d H:i:s e Y', strtotime('+20 minutes'));
$string = "{\"email\":\"JOHNDOE@MAIL.COM\",\"expires\":\"$date\",\"first_name\":\"JOHN\",\"last_name\":\"DOE\",\"day\"}";
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($string, 'AES-256-CBC', $hkey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$sub = preg_replace('/\s/', '', base64_encode($iv . $ciphertext));
$sig = hash_hmac('sha1', $sub, $key, true);
$sig = base64_encode($sig);
$url = 'http://MY_WEBSITE.COM/sso?sso=' . urlencode($sub) . '&signature=' . urlencode($sig);
shell_exec('echo \'' . $url . '\' | pbcopy');
?>
```

And it needs to generate a URL in ASP.NET / C# like the following example:

```
http://YOUR_ONLINE_DOMAIN/sso?sso=1V3VU27wFIERYU0vPFCbU&signature=CsqMu%2F9yc8%3D
```

Can this be done in ASP.NET / C#? Thanks a lot for the help or suggestions!

Comment: I'm sorry - I just don't understand your question. Do you want equivalent of your PHP code in C# or what?

Comment: Yeah, can this form be generated in C#. Or can it be implemented in a .NET Framework application?

Comment: Well... yes, it can.

Comment: Ok I see, but how would you get all those variables into ($url) and pass it on to the browser as a url (like the example above)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are asking for: [ASP.NET Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#url_patterns)